# Se guardan campos salteados del formulario en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Hola gente de la comunidad, vengo con un problema el cual me resulta un poco "raro". Un poco de contexto:

Estoy creando un form para un Examen, el cual tiene una pregunta, la cual es acompañada por los campos, `description`, `iframe` e `image`, la imagen es opcional. Estas preguntas, a su vez tendra su campo `description`, el  `iframe` y una  `image` opcional.

- Para ello, lo que hice fue, en el form crear un array `question[]`
  para almacenar los campos de esa tabla, como lo son
  `question[description]`, `question[iframe]` y `question[image]`
- Para las respuestas aplique algo similar, un array bidimensional
  `answers[][]` en uno guardo el indice de la respuesta y en el otro el
  campo, mis campos son `answers[][description]`, `answers[][iframe]` y
  `answers[][image]`
- Cuando intente insertar solo la descripción y video de la pregunta,
  no hay ningún problema. El problema radica en las respuestas, las
  cuales no todas guardan los campos. Por parte de
  `answers[][description]` el primer campo si guarda, el segundo ya no,
  el tercero si y, el cuarto no.
- En `answers[][iframe]` sucede lo mismo, nadamas que, el primer campo
  no guarda, el segundo si, el tercero no y el cuarto si.

En la siguiente imagen muestro el problema de las repuestas y sus campos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la foto donde se miran los campos de las preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por su parte la pregunta y el `iframe` no tienen ese problema.

Una vez expuesto el contexto, adjunto mis archivos.

El primero es el model `Question`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'iframe', 'image' ,'exam_id'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Exam(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
    }

    public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

debo aclarar que, en mi migracion, la imagen es nulleable, así que no habría problema con ella.

El model de `Answer`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model{    
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'iframe', 'question_id'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

Y el `QuestionController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exam;
use App\Http\Requests\QuestionRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Question;

use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;

class QuestionController extends Controller{
    
    public function create(Exam $exam){

        return view('question.create', compact(['exam']));
    }
    
    public function store(Exam $exam, QuestionRequest $request){
        
        $data = request()->validate([
            'question.description' => 'required',
            'question.iframe' => 'required',
            'answers.*.description' => 'required',
            'answers.*.iframe' => 'required',
        ]);
        dd($data);

        $question = $exam->questions()->create($data['question']);
        $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
         
        return redirect('/exams/'. $exam->id);
    }
}
```

Uso un Request File en donde agregue los mensajes de validación para cada campo.

El `QuestionRequest`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class QuestionRequest extends FormRequest{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(){
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(){
        return [
            'question.description' => 'required',
            'question.iframe' => 'required',
            'answers.*.description' => 'required',
            'answers.*.iframe' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages(){
        return[
            'question.description.required' => 'Debes agregar una descripcion al campo Descripcion.',
            'question.iframe.required' => 'Debes agregar el link del video al campo Video Asociado.',
            'answers.*.description.required' => 'Debes agregar una respuesta en el campo Respuesta',
            'answers.*.iframe.required' => 'Debes agregar un video en el campo Video Asociado'
        ];
    }
}
```

Las migraciones de mi tablas son las siguientes:

Para la tabla `Answers`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAnswersTable extends Migration{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();

            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('iframe');
            $table->text('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('answers');
    }
}
```

Y para la tabla `Questions`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){

        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('exam_id')->unsigned();

            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('iframe');
            $table->text('image')->nullable();
            
            $table->timestamps(); 

            $table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo, mi vista `create.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span>Crear nueva pregunta</span>
                        <a href="/exams/" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" onclick="return confirm('Tus datos se perderan ¿Deseas regresar a la pagina principal?')">Regresar</a>
                    </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           @if($errors->any())
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <h6>Por favor, verifica que los campos esten llenos</h6>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form action="/exams/{{ $exam->id }}/questions" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @CSRF

                                <input hidden name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="description">Descripcion de la pregunta *</label>
                                    <textarea name="question[description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" aria-describedby="descriptionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la pregunta">{{ old('question.description') }}</textarea>
                                    <small id="descriptionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Escribe la descripcion de la pregunta.</small>
                                
                                   
                                    @if($errors->has('question.description'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            {{ $errors->first('question.description') }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                    <textarea name="question[iframe]" type="text" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('question.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                    <small id="iframeHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserta la url del video.</small>
                                    
                                    @if($errors->has('question.iframe'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            {{  $errors->first('question.iframe') }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                {{-- <div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
                                    <label for="image">Imagen asociada</label>
                                    <input name="question[image]" type="file" class="py-2">
                                </div> --}}
                                <hr>
                                
                                <legend>Respuestas</legend>
                                        <span id="choiceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Por favor ingresa las posibles respuestas.</span>
                                        <br>
                                        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="option1" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion A</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option1" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la primera respuesta">{{ old('answers.0.description') }}</textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.0.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.0.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif

                                           <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video" >{{ old('answers.0.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.0.iframe'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.0.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif

                                        {{--<div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">
                                                
                                            </div> --}}
                                        </div> 
                                        
                                        <hr><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="option2" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion B</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option2" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la segunda respuesta" >{{ old('answers.1.description') }}</textarea>
                                            
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.1.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.1.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>
                                        
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                            <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('answers.1.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                                
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.1.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.1.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                        
                                    {{--     <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">
                                                
                                            </div>  --}}                                       
                                        </div>

                                        <hr><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion C</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option3" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la tercera respuesta">{{ old('answers.2.description') }}</textarea>
                                                
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.2.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.2.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('answers.2.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                            
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.2.iframe'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.2.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                    {{--    <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">
                                            </div> --}}

                                        
                                        </div>

                                        <hr><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion D</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option4" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la cuarta respuesta">{{ old('answers.3.description') }}</textarea>
                                                
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.3.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.3.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('answers.3.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                            
                                            @if($errors->has('answers.3.iframe'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.3.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                            {{--  <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">
                                            </div> --}}

                                        
                                        </div>
                                    <hr><br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar pregunta</button>
                                
                            </form>
   

                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Actualización:

Agrego lo que el dd($data) me devuelve a la hora de mandar la información

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "rpKkqpr9zmE7Q1ZN8L9CkQ42HJcDY4oi35aDhAqv"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "question" => array:2 [▼
    "description" => "https://youtu.be/ArMga9b77Fs"
    "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/y2TAeAzeqo4"
  ]
  "answers" => array:8 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "weuohqwepqjwe"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "ouwhdouhqw"
    ]
    3 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/1_nHJPGJvIo"
    ]
    4 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "iuoashdahsoduasd"
    ]
    5 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ"
    ]
    6 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "wiodjoiashd"
    ]
    7 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tenés en como estás armando el array `answers` en el formulario.

El array debería quedar así:

```
'answers' => [
    0 => [
        'description' => 'weuohqwepqjwe',
        'iframe'      => 'https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ',
    ],
    1 => [
        'description' => 'ouwhdouhqw',
        'iframe'      => 'https://youtu.be/1_nHJPGJvIo',
    ],
];
```

Es decir, cada clave contiene todos los campos de la respuesta.

Armar los campos de esta manera:

```
answers[][description]
answers[][iframe]

answers[][description]
answers[][iframe]
```

Es lo mismo que decir:

```
answers[0][description]
answers[1][iframe]

answers[2][description]
answers[3][iframe]
```

Lo que tenés que hacer es, en tu código HTML, agregarle una clave a cada elemento del array a mano:

```
answers[0][description]
answers[0][iframe]

answers[1][description]
answers[1][iframe]
```

Comment: Es la solución correcta. Tuve el mismo issue, porque teníamos que incluir archivos y sólo podíamos usar un FormData. Si construyes la petición con JSON es otra opción en mi opinión más clara, pero eso depende ya de tu método para enviar los datos.

Comment: Gracias viejo, me funciono.